# Recovering from bad superblock on external drive

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, superblock

read a few similar questions/posts and tried the solutions, still stuck. My scenario is simple, external ext4 drive was powered off (via cat) while operating, and failed to mount on boot. As I dug deeper, it got darker:

```
lars@whorus:~$ sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sdc3 /media/lars/external
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc3,

lars@whorus:~$ sudo fsck -fr /dev/sdc3
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
** /dev/sdc3
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
   Invalid B-tree node size
(4, 0)
** Volume check failed.

lars@whorus:~$ sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdc3
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
122085376 inodes, 488337654 blocks
24416882 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4294967296
14903 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848

lars@whorus:~$ sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdc3
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdc3

lars@whorus:~$ testdisk
Command line: TestDisk

TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org
OS: Linux, kernel 3.13.0-33-generic (#58-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 29 16:45:05 UTC 2014) x86_64
Compiler: GCC 4.8
Compilation date: 2013-10-29T01:29:29
ext2fs lib: 1.42.9, ntfs lib: libntfs-3g, reiserfs lib: none, ewf lib: none
/dev/sda: LBA, HPA, LBA48, DCO support
/dev/sda: size       1953523055 sectors
/dev/sda: user_max   1953523055 sectors
/dev/sda: native_max 1953525168 sectors
/dev/sda: dco        1953525168 sectors
/dev/sdb: LBA, HPA, LBA48, DCO support
/dev/sdb: size       321670847 sectors
/dev/sdb: user_max   321670847 sectors
/dev/sdb: native_max 321672960 sectors
/dev/sdb: dco        321672960 sectors
Warning: can't get size for Disk /dev/mapper/control - 0 B - 1 sectors, sector size=512
Hard disk list
Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63, sector size=512 - WDC WD10EZEX-00KUWA0, S/N:WD-WMC1S7063930, FW:15.01H15
Disk /dev/sdb - 164 GB / 153 GiB - CHS 20023 255 63, sector size=512 - HDT722516DLA380, S/N:VDB71BTCCZ4KEC, FW:V43OA80A
Disk /dev/sdc - 2000 GB / 1862 GiB - CHS 243197 255 63, sector size=512 - WD My Book 111D, FW:1049

Partition table type (auto): Mac
Disk /dev/sdc - 2000 GB / 1862 GiB - WD My Book 111D
Partition table type: Mac

Interface Advanced

HFS+ magic value at 16/82/3
 1 P partition_map                  1         63         63
 2 P Free                          64     262207     262144
 3 P HFS                       262208 3906963439 3906701232
     HFS+ blocksize=4096, 2000 GB / 1862 GiB
 4 P Free                  3906963440 3906963455         16

HFS_HFSP_boot_sector
 3 P HFS                       262208 3906963439 3906701232
     HFS+ blocksize=4096, 2000 GB / 1862 GiB

HFS+ magic value at 16/82/3

HFS+ magic value at 16/82/3
Volume header
HFS+ OK

Backup volume header
HFS+ OK

Sectors are identical.
Superblock                        Backup superblock
0000 482b0004 80000900   H+......  482b0004 80000900   H+......
0008 6673636b 00003a38   fsck..:8  6673636b 00003a38   fsck..:8
0010 ca703bfa d0dcbf86   .p;.....  ca703bfa d0dcbf86   .p;.....
0018 00000000 ca709e6a   .....p.j  00000000 ca709e6a   .....p.j
0020 00007269 00000a94   ..ri....  00007269 00000a94   ..ri....
0028 00001000 1d1b70f6   ......p.  00001000 1d1b70f6   ......p.
0030 07a1ba60 125a6e5c   ...`.Zn\  07a1ba60 125a6e5c   ...`.Zn\
0038 00010000 00010000   ........  00010000 00010000   ........
0040 00026064 00000000   ..`d....  00026064 00000000   ..`d....
0048 00000000 00000083   ........  00000000 00000083   ........
0050 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0058 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0060 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0068 109ee824 e4771b69   ...$.w.i  109ee824 e4771b69   ...$.w.i
0070 00000000 03a37000   ......p.  00000000 03a37000   ......p.
0078 00000000 00003a37   ......:7  00000000 00003a37   ......:7
0080 00000001 00003a37   ......:7  00000001 00003a37   ......:7
0088 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0090 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0098 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
00A0 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
00A8 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
00B0 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
00B8 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
00C0 00000000 01c00000   ........  00000000 01c00000   ........
00C8 00000000 00001c00   ........  00000000 00001c00   ........
00D0 0000d239 00000e00   ...9....  0000d239 00000e00   ...9....
00D8 08b60936 00000e00   ...6....  08b60936 00000e00   ...6....
00E0 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
00E8 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
00F0 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
00F8 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0100 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0108 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0110 00000000 05000000   ........  00000000 05000000   ........
0118 05000000 00005000   ......P.  05000000 00005000   ......P.
0120 125a6e5c 00005000   .Zn\..P.  125a6e5c 00005000   .Zn\..P.
0128 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0130 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0138 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0140 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0148 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0150 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0158 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
0160 00000000 05000000   ........  00000000 05000000   ........
0168 00000000 00005000   ......P.  00000000 00005000   ......P.
0170 00080dd5 00000024   .......$  00080dd5 00000024   .......$
0178 00d26916 000000dc   ..i.....  00d26916 000000dc   ..i.....
0180 00d271ba 00000066   ..q....f  00d271ba 00000066   ..q....f
0188 0146e7eb 0000004a   .F.....J  0146e7eb 0000004a   .F.....J
0190 0146dd38 00000034   .F.8...4  0146dd38 00000034   .F.8...4
0198 015f75aa 00004e1c   ._u...N.  015f75aa 00004e1c   ._u...N.
01A0 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01A8 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01B0 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01B8 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01C0 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01C8 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01D0 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01D8 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01E0 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01E8 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01F0 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........
01F8 00000000 00000000   ........  00000000 00000000   ........

HFS_HFSP_boot_sector
 3 P HFS                       262208 3906963439 3906701232
     HFS+ blocksize=4096, 2000 GB / 1862 GiB

HFS+ magic value at 16/82/3

HFS+ magic value at 16/82/3
Volume header
HFS+ OK

Backup volume header
HFS+ OK

Sectors are identical.

HFS_HFSP_boot_sector
 3 P HFS                       262208 3906963439 3906701232
     HFS+ blocksize=4096, 2000 GB / 1862 GiB

HFS+ magic value at 16/82/3

HFS+ magic value at 16/82/3
Volume header
HFS+ OK

Backup volume header
HFS+ OK

Sectors are identical.
New options :
 Dump : No
 Align partition: Yes
 Expert mode : No

TestDisk exited normally.
```

I tried using all the listed backup blocks with e2fsck, but they all came back the same as invalid. Tried restoring the backup one via testdisk, still the same. Hoping to restore the drive without a low level dd= type solution, as I don't have 2TB of storage available for the image :( On the plus side, this isn't the system volume, so it's easy to attempt to mount/unmount without other issues.

All help is appreciated, I've got about 20 tabs of forum posts open that tend to end in sad stories.

Comment: about checking/wiping/saving/restoring superblocks specifically - do `man wipefs`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you immediately make a mirror of the damaged drive to avoid losing any more information.  Your hardware is most likely bad and I would not mess with it further unless you like frustration.

You can try to recover the image after restoriing it to a new disk.  But I'm betting unless the data is extremely important that will be a time consumming and frustrating effort.

Unfortunately, I think your best approach is to remove the old disk, install a new one, and restore from those fine backups you should be keeping.

Comment: New internal drive on the way to avoid this headache in the future. Normally I'd dump the contents of the drive, but this is the network storage drive. I should have some redundancy with a dropbox store, but I'd like to avoid actual loss. Of the ~1.5 TB only ~1-2 gigs are stuff I need to save, so crossing my fingers.